# Query on SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE schema taking long time to run

Tags: performance, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run a simple query against any of the tables contained in SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE schema but for some reason it is taking up a long time to run even if I try to limit it to show only the first row, like the following example:

```
SELECT * FROM "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."ACCESS_HISTORY" limit 1;
```

Is that a normal behavior? If not, can someone help me to figure out why this is happening?

Comment: What does query profile  (query execution plan)shows? can you figure out what's the bottleneck by looking at it?

Comment: What is considered a long time?  All of those views are secure views and can sometimes that a little bit of time to come back with results.  But no more than several seconds for a `LIMIT 1`.  If it is taking over a minute, for example, you may want to reach out to support and see if something is going on.

Comment: Using the command I have posted here it was taking more than 5 minutes even with the "LIMIT 1". After adding "WHERE QUERY_START_TIME > CURRENT_DATE() - 1 
limit 1;" statement I have got the result within 35 seconds. I am still not sure if this is an appropriate time to return a result, as I wanted to analyze some old records and it would take a long time to do any processing with this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its always a good practice to add a WHERE condition so the optimizer can make use of query pruning.
If you know your objects were accessed within the past say 24 hours, can you add a date filter and see if that helps?

```
SELECT * FROM "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."ACCESS_HISTORY" 
WHERE QUERY_START_TIME > CURRENT_DATE() - 1 
limit 1;
```

More info on mirco-partitions and query pruning: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tables-clustering-micropartitions.html#query-pruning

Comment: Good @Paul. I was also leaning towards same; however, could not find any conclusive from profiler. In case you have any sample case to showcase as well and you can add to your answer, it will be more helpful.

Comment: Snowflake does not make this information available as documented in the secure view docs. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/views-secure.html#scanned-data-size

Performance will be quite variable based on the size and usage patterns of your Snowflake Account. Anecdotally, I just re-ran a test and not using the filter took 14s. using the  START_TIME > CURRENT_DATE()-.1 filter took 1.3s.

Comment: Thanks @PaulNeedleman, that helped to lower the processing time to 33 seconds with the "LIMIT 1" condition, is that even a normal time to get a response back?